# Backing up chrome's bookmarks and history

Tags: google-chrome, backup

I'm reinstalling my OS and I wanted to save the current state of Google chrome i.e. bookmarks, history and saved passwords.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on your version of chrome you can do this:

- enable the `sync` feature of chrome, sync your stuff to the cloud. that will include passwords, bookmarks, themes, extensions. reinstall your OS, reinstall chrome, reenable sync .. back are your things (yes, history is not among it). read more about `sync` over [here](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139).
- zip the folder `%APPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data` (or any other backup mechanism) and then reinstall your OS, reinstall chrome and unzip your zip